# Image Hashing in Django

Tags: django, image, hash, web-scraping

I'm a beginner programmer building a Django web application that goes to a bunch of places on the internet and scrapes for advertisements.  Here's a shortened version of my Ad model:

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    ...  
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', blank=True)
```

My celery task creates these ad models and saves them to the database with accompanying images.  The task (shortened again) follows:

```
class DownloadAds(PeriodicTask):
    run_every=timedelta(minutes = 5)

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        logger = self.get_logger(**kwargs)
        logger.info("Downloading ads.")


        a1 = Ad(...)
        a1.save()

        name = image_urls[b] # url for image
        result = urllib.urlretrieve(name)        
        a1.pic.save(
            os.path.basename(name),
            File(open(result[0]))
                    )
```

The code currently works as intended, but it downloads every image it encounters, regardless of whether or not it already has it in the database.  To avoid future space issues, I want to implement image hashing, but I'm not really sure how to go about doing that.  Any advice/direction would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just made each picture a new model and checked to see if it existed.  It was definitely the easier approach.